# Redirecting one file to another using dup2 and strtok

Tags: c

I have to write a program, in which I need to use strtok and dup2 to redirect one file to another, but I need to also have the user to actually put the command cat < file1 > file2, but not from the shell, but instead by using my program. That's why I need strtok. And the reason my program doesn't work is probably because of that, because I don't really understand how strtok works. I found a similar program on the internet, but they just take the ls command and redirect it to the file. That's it. My program is much more complicated. I mean, it would've been easier just to say in shell cat < file1 > file2, but for some reason they want us to do it this way. 
So, anyways, here is what I have so far (here I just combined what I have found on the internet with what I already had from before. We had to do something similar but then the user would just go ls or ls -l. Very simple stuff. This is much harder, for me, at least.)

```
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <sys/wait.h>
 #include <string.h>


 int main() {
     pid_t pid;
     char line[256];
     char *args[129];
     int i;
     int fd;
     int status;
     char *temp;

     while (1) {
            printf(">");
            if (fgets(line, 256, stdin) == 0) {
                 exit(0);
        }
            else {
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0) {
                i = 0;
                temp = strtok("<",line);
                while (temp != NULL) {
                   args[i++] = temp;
                   temp = strtok(">",line);
                   args[i] = '\0';
                 }
                fd = open("hello", O_RDONLY);
                dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
                fd = open("world", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
                dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO );
                close(fd);
                execvp(args[0], args); 
               } 

              else {
                  close(fd);
                  wait(&status);
              }
            }
       } 
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's a helpful reference on strtok: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: Note that in a 'real' shell, you can write `command > file2 < file1` as equivalent to `command < file1 > file2`.  Also, there do not have to be spaces around the redirections: `command >file2 <file1` works too.  And `strtok()` tramples on the original string, so you can't tell what character was there.  In your code it does not matter, but if you generalized, it would.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the backwards `strtok` arguments, there are other problems.

- the parent process closes `fd` which it never opened (it's an uninitialized variable there, so you're closing a random fd that may not exist)
- the child process does two opens and two dup2's but only one close. You're leaking an fd.
- hardcoded filenames
- you look for a single "<" but have a loop for detecting multiple ">"s
- lack of `<stdlib.h>` for `exit()`
- who really thinks `S_IRWXU` is more readable than `0700`?

And if you're aiming to approximate the behavior of a real shell, you should at least ignore whitespace around the redirection operators.

Comment: OK, how to get just dup2 to work, though? I changed the code a little bit, and now it look like this around the opening and closing fds. Never mind the file's hardcoded names for now. I just want to get it to work, because it doesn't work right now either. I will deal with strtok later.

Comment: pid = fork();
                if (pid == 0) {
                  fd = open("hello", O_RDONLY);
                  dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
                  close(fd);
                  fd = open("world", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU);
                  dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO );
                  close(fd);

Comment: @SergiyZakharov I just noticed your strtok loop is infinite because you are starting from the beginning each time. It's not even getting to the dup'ing part.

Comment: I guess it's not the only problem, because dup2 doesn't even work all by itself.

Comment: can you show a stripped down complete program without any of the strtok, just the fork/open/dup2/exec part?

Comment: Very few programs should make their outputs executable; the S_IRWXU should probably be better as 0600 or 0644.  Personally, I'm very reluctant to make a file publicly writable, even if users can set their umask to prevent that happening, so I don't usually use the classic but somewhat insecure 0666 mode.